# CORS Error when including scripts in Node JS Pug Template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have an express server which uses the PUG as a template engine. I am trying to add tailwind CSS using the cdn but I'm getting a cors error like this:

> Error: Access to script at 'https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

In my pug template this is my base file where I m trying to include the script:

```
html
  head
    block head
      meta(charset='UTF-8')
      meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
      link(rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css')
      link(rel='shortcut icon' type='image/png' href='/img/favicon.png')
      link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,700')
      title A & N Tours | #{title}
  
  body
    // HEADER
    include _header
        
    // CONTENT
    block content
      h1 This is a placeholder heading
      
    // FOOTER
    include _footer
    
    script(src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/" crossorigin="") 
    script(src='/js/bundle.js')
    script(src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com" crossorigin="" defer)
```

My route handler function:

```
  const tours = await Tour.find().limit(3);
  res.status(200).render('homepage', {
    title: 'Home',
    topTours: tours
  })
});
```

Comment: maybe try first add Access-Control-Allow-Origin as *

Answer (score 1):

The resource that you request from tailwindcss.com does not come with CORS headers. But because of the [`crossorigin=""`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin) attribute, the browser expects them.

The problem goes away if you omit this attribute

```
script(src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com" defer)
```

Is there a particular reason why you set the attribute?

The following HTML page loads without problems:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com" defer>
  </script>
</head></html>
```

Comment: I was trying to debug the problem and somewhere I read that adding this attribute should solve the problem, so I added it. But now after removing the attribute I m getting another error : GET https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 302

Comment: See my edited answer. Without pug, I am able to load the script.