# Why my CORS policy is not allowing to get a script file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors, netlify

i am experiencing an issue with the CORS policy of my application, even though I have allowed all origins and resources. Whenever I try to make a request to the server, I encounter an error in the console due to CORS problems. Specifically, this is the error:

```
Access to script at `https://siteA.com/vite/assets/scriptA.b8672433.js` from origin `https://www.siteB.com` has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I changed the URLs for privacy reasons related to the company I work for, but the current structure is as follows:

- siteA.com - Contains all the content to be presented on siteB
  (original URL: siteA.com/route)
- siteB.com - Has a redirect
  (siteB.com/route) so that when the user accesses it, they maintain
  the domain siteB.com/route while displaying the content of siteA.

Currently, the siteB application is hosted on Netlify, and I have already defined CSP rules in the `_headers` file to allow the loading of external scripts.

For siteA, which is a Rails application, I have defined the following rule using the 'rack-cors' gem:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors, :debug => true, :logger => (-> { Rails.logger }) do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get]
    end
  end
```

This way, I am enabling the delivery of this file from the server of siteA to siteB. However, CORS continues to block me, and I don't know what else to do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS Error when including scripts in Node JS Pug Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71985454/cors-error-when-including-scripts-in-node-js-pug-template) Otherwise, please give more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve my problem. I even removed the crossorigin attribute from the import of my script; however, it is still being blocked by CORS.

And I can't provide much more information about the issue since I don't know much about what's happening to cause the blockage. Essentially, it's as stated in the above question: when I access websiteB.com/route, it blocks the loading of the script file.